# string contains 5 numbers and line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, stripos

I am looping trough a txt file which contains lines for example:

```
asdasdasd
lorem ipsum
lorem 12345-1
more lorem ipsum bacon
```

From this I need to know when the line founds text **12345-1**

Lorem in the beging is inrelative.

Can I use stripos like

```
if (stripos('/^[1-9]{0,5}$-1/', $line) !== false)
```

I dont know the right regex. Of course the 12345 can be what ever, but its always 5 digits and ends with -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a 5-digit chunk followed with `-1`, you may use

```
/\b[0-9]{5}-1\b/
```

Or, if word boundaries (`\b`) is too restrictive, use lookarounds:

```
/(?<!\d)\d{5}-1(?!\d)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AppIfv/1)

**Use it with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**:

```
if (preg_match('/\b[0-9]{5}-1\b/', $line))
{
     echo "Found!";
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary (or `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind making the regex fail if there is a digit before the current location)
- `[0-9]{5}` - 5 digits
- `-1` -  a literal char sequence `-1`
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary (or `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead making the regex fail if there is a digit right after the current location)